# django session data not being saved

Tags: python, django, database, session, telegram

Little explanation of what i'm doing: I've a simple telegram bot that sends a link to the user, the link is a twitch login page to authentificate the user and giving me permission to do some twitch stuffs. More in details the user click the link, do the twitch login and then is redirected to mysite.com/verify where all the oidc authentification things are made, then if everything is correct i want to add both twitch id and telegram id of the user to an external database.

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def telegramBot(request): #function to handle telegram webhook
    print("telegramBot request.session", request.session) 

    for key, value in request.session.items(): #printing all value in session
        print('{} => {}'.format(key, value))

    request.session['telegramid'] = "12345"    #trying to add data
 
    for key, value in request.session.items(): #checking if there is the new value
        print('{} => {}'.format(key, value))   #here it correctly prints telegramid => 12345

    request.session.modified = True

    if request.method == 'POST':
        [code to handle telegram messages]
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('get',status=200)

#mysite.it/verify/
#the user is redirected here after login with twitch
def verify(request):
    print("verify request.session", request.session)

    for key, value in request.session.items(): #PROBLEM! It prints nothing,
        print('{} => {}'.format(key, value))   #where is the telegram id previously set? 
                                              
    request.session['twitchid'] = "twitchid"   #trying to add a new value

    for key, value in request.session.items():
        print('{} => {}'.format(key, value))   #correctly prints twitch id and nothing else

    [code to do the oidc authentification]

    externalDatabase.insert(telegramID,twitchID) #adding data to database, pseudocode
    
    return HttpResponse("<h2>You can go back to the telegram bot</h2>")
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    'django_filters',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

When i print "request.session" i see something like: <django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore object at 0x7f9245469b25>
in both functions so i think i'm trying to access the same "piece of memory" which i think it's correct. But why when i try to print value of that session (from another view) it prints nothing? I think i wrote everything necessary but let me know if you need other informations. Thanks

PS: don't know if it's relevant or it just gonna confuse, anyway: i started working this django app locally (DATABASES in the settings.py was set to connect to a mongo db database), now i'm hosting it at pythonanywhere and set back the DATABASES values in settings.py back to default (and now i comunicate with that mongodb database through pymongo)

Comment: Check if the domain URL does not change between requests. Like if the first request is made to www.mysite.com and another one to mysite.com (no www) - session is not saved.

Comment: The telegram webhook is to `https://www.mysite.it/telegrambot/` and the redirect url from twitch after the login is to `https://www.mysite.it/verify/`,  anyway now happens something strange, the print of the request.session in telegramBot is always the same, while the print in verify keeps changing this part "0x7f9245469b25" but now the request.session have the twitch id value

Comment: @manuersuper Maybe a small step forward would be checking actual session key instead of session repr (just to be sure the views are accessing the same db object), so instead of printing `request.session` try `request.session.session_key`?

Comment: @caseneuve good idea, if i print the session key in the telegramBot(request) function the key is None, does it suggests something to you? sorry for the late reply